# Change format of the date in SQL/Convert the SQL date

Tags: mysql, sql-server, date

So, I am running the following SQL Query listed below.  I need to change the EXT_FIRSTINSTALL date format, I am not sure how to do that.

Current EXT_FIRSTINSTALL = 28-JAN-2015 00:00:00

New EXT_FIRSTINSTALL = 28/01/2015

```
SELECT EXT_ASSETNAME, STATUS, EXT_FIRSTINSTALL, CLASSSTRUCTUREID 
FROM MAXPRD.ASSET 
WHERE SITEID IN ('OPS','STORE') AND STATUS NOT IN ('RETIRED', 'DECOMMISSIONED') 
    AND CLASSSTRUCTUREID IN ('4921','4939');
```

Comment: Is it SQL server or MySQL?

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are **not** the same, and it's highly unlikely you're using both. Please use only tags that are actually relevant to your code, and don't just randomly grab those that look or sound alike. Tags have specific meanings here. If you're not sure if a tag applies, carefully read it's description. If you're still not sure, don't use it. Please [edit] your question to remove the tag that does not apply, to make it clear what you're asking. The two (very different) DBMSs have different syntax and functionality, so knowing which you're using is highly relevant.

Comment: If you're storing your dates in anything other than a `DATE` or `DATETIME` column you're missing the point of a relational database. I strongly encourage you to use the [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) when storing or manipulating dates. Using any other standard is always problematic. If you want the date to look a particular way on the client side, do that formatting in your application layer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using this if you are using SQL Server also refer this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sql-server-2008-date-format.aspx

```
SELECT EXT_ASSETNAME, STATUS, CONVERT (varchar(10),EXT_FIRSTINSTALL,103), CLASSSTRUCTUREID 
FROM MAXPRD.ASSET 
WHERE SITEID IN ('OPS','STORE') AND STATUS NOT IN ('RETIRED', 'DECOMMISSIONED') 
    AND CLASSSTRUCTUREID IN ('4921','4939');
```